# New to Git - Needing to understand if Dropbox is going to hamper it?

Tags: git, macos, asp.net-core, dropbox, visual-studio-code

I'm a 20+ year Microsoft developer and I've used SourceSafe forever so I understand source control per se. In an attempt to move with the times I'm doing some work in ASP.Net Core and I have two Macs I'll be working on. I've got Visual Studio Code etc, all good there. I create a project on Mac 1, setup a repo on visualstudio.com and my work and commits are all good. Occasionally I have to visit my client and I take with me a MacBook Pro. To keep stuff in sync between the two machines I've always used Dropbox.

I'm just needing to understand what happens with the file replication - if the project has files on the iMac at home and they get synced to the MacBook by the wonders of Dropbox, what happens there? Is the project still under source control on the MacBook as well (I've not setup any Git on it at all). Presumably I can't commit back to the central repository from there? The files just get synced back to the home machine via Dropbox and I commit them when I get home after the meeting?
Should I have a separate branch or fork or something on the laptop and stop Dropbox syncing this folder altogether?

I've learned quite a lot of Git-related phrases in the last fortnight but I'm not sure I understand them all just yet! If anyone can clear the fog for me I'd be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/anishathalye/git-remote-dropbox

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Mercurial to Git, but I think the same issues – vis a vis Dropbox – apply to both, here.

In short: I wouldn't use Dropbox to do the syncing.

The main thing that can go wrong here is if Dropbox (or similar) decides to sync a repository directory (`.hg` or `.git`) at the same time as Mercurial/Git does.  That could create a very Bad Day At The Office as the repository gets corrupted.  It takes rather bad luck for that to happen, but it has happened to me twice in the past, when I had the same bright idea as you.

Also, you're using two (broadly) ‘syncing’ technologies on top of each other, here, and that's asking quietly for trouble.

What I now routinely do is either use a (public or private) repository on bitbucket.org, or create a repository on a machine I can ssh to, and clone that repository to each of the machines I'll be working on.  That means that I share the code *entirely via Mercurial*.

Downsides:

- requires another service (bitbucket) or ssh-accessible machine, which may be inconvenient for some reason (but this isn't really more of a hassle or information-leak than using Dropbox);
- you can only share complete commits (but it's probably a good habit to aim for, to make your commits small and atomic enough that this isn't more than a minor irritant);
- you do occasionally forget where such-and-such an edit was! (but that's a separate bit of process you might aim to fix).

Upsides:

- you're using the tool – Mercurial or Git – as it's intended, and in a pretty reliable mode;
- the various copies are completely separate from each other, so there's a limit to how much of your work you can accidentally wreck at once.